# Mysql filter data by current date

Tags: mysql

I am having a table like..

```
    | id | name             | meetingID | meeting_type | status | recurring_time | attendee_passwd | moderator_passwd | date_created        | timezone  | meeting_datetime    | reminder | duration | created_by_id | sms_no | conferenceID | meeting_logout_url | max_participants | participants_id |
    +----+------------------+-----------+--------------+--------+----------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------+----------+---------------+--------+--------------+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|  7 | 6august          | REG_524   |              |   NULL |                | 90200           | 18614            | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | GMT  5.45 | 2012-08-06 03:00:00 |        0 | 60       |             1 |  12356 |         NULL | http://log.com     |               20 |            NULL |
```

I am trying to filter the table by current date so for i am using the following query

```
 SELECT *  from demo_meeting WHERE created_by_id IN(SELECT id FROM demo_user WHERE user_name = ' Sang') and meeting_datetime=curdate();
```

But i am getting the empty set instead of getting the result.

please tell me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Even i am getting the empty set for         select * from demo_meeting WHERE meeting_datetime = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%YY %MM %DD %HH %MM %SS');     this one also

Comment: Empty set means QUERY is correct but CONDITIONS are WRONG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are comparing a datetime with a date.

Try casting your datetime to a date, like this:

```
SELECT *  from demo_meeting WHERE created_by_id IN ( SELECT id FROM demo_user WHERE user_name = ' Sang') AND DATE(meeting_datetime) = curdate();
```

Comment: thanks guys actually both the answers are correct i was doing mistakes somwher else

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *  from demo_meeting WHERE created_by_id IN(SELECT id FROM demo_user WHERE user_name = ' Sang') and DATE_FORMAT(meeting_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')=curdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

try to format your date using `DATE( )` function. BTW, joining of tables is *much more efficient* than `SubQuery`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    demo_meeting a 
            INNER JOIN demo_user b
                ON a.created_by_id = b.ID
WHERE   b.user_name = 'Sang' AND
        DATE(a.meeting_datetime) = DATE(curdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing curdate() with the field meeting_datetime which is having datatype datetime/timestamp; what you exactly need to do is compare like date(meeting_datetime) with curdate().

query will be:
 SELECT *  from demo_meeting WHERE created_by_id IN(SELECT id FROM demo_user WHERE user_name = ' Sang') and `date(meeting_datetime)=curdate();`

Hope it will help you out.